# iPhone Toolbar Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a toolbar on the bottom of my view, and I want to hide the toolbar, how is this accomplished?  I only have the original view that was in the project, I tried the code below but no success.

```
[self.view setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
toolBarName.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: The setToolbarHidden is a method of the navigation controller class. Unless your view is UINavigationController it won't work. And every view has a "hidden" properly which can be set to "YES" or "NO". Also, toolBarHidden is a property of UIToolBar too.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above poster, if you wanted the animation in there you should be able to call:

```
[toolBarName setToolBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

if you want the animation to be in there.